# How to solve minimax optimization problem in python?

Tags: python, optimization, cvxopt

Following minimax problem transformation instruction, I define the problem as below:

```
min z  
s.t. z >= f_i(x)
```

My question is, in cvxopt, if I declare z as variable, what is the efficient way to build the constraints list? I was try to build a vector [z, z, z, ..., z].T, so that I can use Ax < b as constrains, but I don't know how create this vector.

Answer (score 0):

Now I found answer, to close this thread

```
1.T * z
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also try this to get a more accurate value 
1.5*z